# git protocol connection refused

Tags: git, remote-repository

I created a GIT Remote Repository in localhost.
Then I push my project.
I can clone my project via :

```
git clone ssh://127.0.0.1/repo-r/haq
```

But when I want to use `git://` or `http://` I get the following error:

```
$ git clone git://127.0.0.1/repo-r/haq/haq.git
Cloning into 'haq'...
fatal: unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:
127.0.0.1[0: 127.0.0.1]: errno=Connection refused
```

How do I solve it?

Comment: Setting up an https server is nontrivial. The [Pro Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) covers some of the basics, but there's a lot of OS and server-software dependencies and a whole lot of perpetual ongoing security issues (you may want a full time person just to keep things up to date security wise).

Comment: You might be overselling the complexity a bit. But yes, it takes a line of your package manager to install the http daemon and Verbot, it takes adapting a configuration file example from a website, and it takes setting up a domain and letsencrypt so that a trusted connection can be established

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not running a http server, so you cannot use http to access your repo. It's as simple as that.

Same for the (mostly obsolete) git protocol.

When setting up a http server for git access, you typically have bare repos where you push to from your working non-bare repos. You would not use the same repo.

Answer (score 0):

For local repositories (on localhost), the [local protocol](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#_the_protocols) remains the most straightforward

> The most basic is the Local protocol, in which the remote repository is in another directory on the same host.
>
> This is often used if everyone on your team has access to a shared filesystem such as an NFS mount, or in the less likely case that everyone logs in to the same computer.
> The latter wouldn’t be ideal, because all your code repository instances would reside on the same computer, making a catastrophic loss much more likely.

```
git clone /srv/git/project.git
```